# Displaying fan blades in Java

Tags: java

I do not understand the significance of multiplying by 0.4 in this line:

```
int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4)
```

in the code below. how are they calculating the radius beneath

```
//Displaying fan blades in Java
package graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawFan extends JFrame {

    public DrawFan() {
        setTitle("The Four Fan Blades");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new BladesPanel());
    }

    class BladesPanel extends JPanel {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
            int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
            int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

            int x = xCenter - radius;
            int y = yCenter - radius;

            g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
            g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
            g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
            g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawArcs2 fanBlades = new DrawArcs2();
        fanBlades.setSize(300,300);
        fanBlades.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: They just don't want the drawing to occupy the whole window.  If the radius is 0.4 - or 40% - of the window size, the whole circle will be 80%.

Comment: Don't understand why this question is getting down votes __without__ explicit comments. Is a valid question, with posted code, asking for some explanation & help. Everyone, regardless how proficient is in a programming language should be welcome to ask...

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);
```

They first get what number is bigger in your JPanel: the width or the height with this part `(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight())`

Imagine height is 400 and width 300. 400 is going to be selected. Now, you want to paint a circle inside this 400-wide rectangle. To fit your circle you need to make it at least 1/2 400 points. That's the same as 400*0.5. To fit better the circle inside, they choose to multiply by 0.4 (or 40% the size of the taller width/height)

Comment: thank you so much guys, I'm satisfied with ur answers. Understood now!@Diego,@Racraman